# Onsen UI Sliding Menu使用時のテーブルリンクについて

Tags: monaca, onsen-ui

ずぶの初心者である私は、Onsen UI Sliding Menuを使用し、タッチしたらページを表示するだけの非常に初歩的なアプリ製作に挑戦しています。

質問の内容
Onsen UI Sliding Menuの１ページに表を作成して表をクリックしたら詳細ページにジャンプするというものを動作させたいと思っています。
しかし、表を作成したあとのリンクの貼り方がよくわかりません。自分なりに調べて、

```
<TD><A HREF=hoge.html">hoge</A></TD>
```

と記述したら、UIが解除された文字のみのページに飛んでしまいました。
Onsen UI Sliding Menuの構成を維持したままジャンプさせる方法を教えてください。

非常に初歩的な質問になってしまって恐縮です。

Answer (score 1):

Onsen UIを使用されているのであれば、<ons-list>を使用すると良いと思います。

```
<ons-list>
    <ons-list-item modifier="chevron" onclick="slider.setMainPage('page2.html')">
    ページが変わります。
    </ons-list-item>
    <ons-list-item modifier="chevron" onclick="ons.navigator.pushPage('page2.html')">
    ページがスライドして変わります。
    </ons-list-item>
</ons-list>
```

上記の

```
onclick="app.slidingMenu.setMainPage('page2.html')"
```

の **app.slidingMenu** には index.html の下記で指定した文字列が入ります。

```
<ons-sliding-menu var="app.slidingMenu"
```